# Custom view data-bind in KnockOutJS

Tags: json, data-binding, knockout.js

I am having problems creating a custom field within KnockOutJS ViewModel.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead><tr>
        <th>name</th><th>abb</th><th>combo</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: clients"><tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Abbreviation"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: NameAbbreviation"></td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function ClientModel() {
    var self = this;
// Bind all data to UI < -- working
    self.clients = ko.observableArray(data);
// Not working        
    self.NameAbbreviation = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Name + " " + self.Abbreviation;
    })
};
ko.applyBindings(new ClientModel());
```

**JOSN DATA** (working)

```
{"ID":14,"GUID":"c999b888-9566-2e50-a23c-07913d389f99","Name":"Aaron46","Abbreviation":"Corporate Customer","Website":"www.ts2mkg3d0oomo.com","Email":"kltuh32@otyvmj.net","Active":true,"ModifyDate":"1959-02-14T15:47:53.43","CreatedDate":"1987-09-26T00:37:13.52","CreatedDateString":"9/26/1987","ModifyDateString":"2/14/1959","Status":0,"Message":null},{"ID":443,"GUID":"12c60aa5-03f1-509c-5d49-9caf696c44ce","Name":"Abigail","Abbreviation":"Technical","Website":"www.wsfj97qccj1.com","Email":"eagai@odgqur.com","Active":true,"ModifyDate":"2007-02-01T06:01:11.3","CreatedDate":"1963-05-11T01:23:21.11","CreatedDateString":"5/11/1963","ModifyDateString":"2/1/2007","Status":0,"Message":null},{"ID":136,"GUID":"63c65e85-0f9b-1f7c-328a-ca253a4881d1","Name":"Adrienne","Abbreviation":"Accounting","Website":"www.ixug6k4eqkjmnr.com","Email":"tqxcjexh.izoiqv@pyuzqk.net","Active":false,"ModifyDate":"2000-12-14T08:11:31.83","CreatedDate":"1980-05-03T03:25:02.34","CreatedDateString":"5/3/1980","ModifyDateString":"12/14/2000","Status":0,"Message":null}
```

I am able to bind all the data with no issues, when I do not create a custom view field!

When I try to create **NameAbbreviation** custom field, I get an error

```
Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: NameAbbreviation is not defined;
Bindings value: text: NameAbbreviation
```

I understand the error, as KO cannot find NameAbbreviation in the view.

How do I get this custom view NameAbbreviation to be used/seen by KO?

Comment: Are Name and Abbreviation ko.observables?  If so, might try: return self.Name() + " " + self.Abbreviation();

Comment: That did not work:  
Object #<ClientModel> has no method 'Name' ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in the `foreach` loop, the scope is the array item that you are looping on.  Your view model has `NameAbbreviation` defined at the root level rather than on each item.

There are several approaches that you could take here.

The simplest is to just create a simple function on your view model that returns the formatted string and bind against it using `$root` or `$parent`.

```
function ClientModel() {
    this.clients = ko.observableArray(data);
    this.NameAbbreviation = function (item) {
        return item.Name + " " + item.Abbreviation;
    };
};
```

Then, in your UI bind like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: clients">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Abbreviation"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $root.NameAbbreviation($data)"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Otherwise, you could consider creating a "item" constructor function that adds the `NameAbbreviation` and then sending each raw data item through the constructor.

Another option would be to use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

Comment: self.FullName = ko.computed(function (item) {
return item.Name + " " + item.Abbreviation;
}) <--  ADDED the ko.computed

However, I am getting ** Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined**

Comment: If this lives on the main view model and is returning the value for each item, then you would not want this to be a `ko.computed`.  It can just be a normal function.

Comment: Ok .. now I am getting a literal string:    "function (item) { return item.Abbreviation() + " " + item.Active(); }"  returned

Comment: I had an error in the answer.  Updated. Need to pass the data, as KO only passes data for handlers (click/event).

Answer (score 0):

```
// use () with item.Name and item.Abbreviation as below

this.NameAbbreviation = function (item) {
        return item.Name() + " " + item.Abbreviation();
    };
```